# Attach file on telegram with long message using php bot

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

How can send long text with file on telegram using php bot without use file caption? Caption has limit 200 character I want attach a file with long text more than 200 characters.I use telegram senddocument method bot it's not send long text.

[see sample demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u9hc.png)

Comment: Please make an attempt on your own, then provide that code in your question.  Asking SO to do something for you is not exactly welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

You can upload the file to a public channel, then include link to the post in your long text.

Comment: A comment would have been enough

Comment: what is the best way to upload a video into Telegram along with a text, in a way which video comes first, then the text has been shown? (without sacrificing the quality)